# LocalStorage on Ubuntu SDK and Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

Well, the thing is that I created an app with LocalStorage from QtQuick and last week it was working well until some update come.

I use the LocalStorage and the file storage.js that I downloaded from http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vthompson/ubuntu-reddit-app/ubuntu-reddit-app/files

It was working very well but since last weekend it doesn't work anymore on the phone, even I reinstalled Ubuntu Touch with the new stable version (r100) and it doesn't work but on the desktop it works.

And other thing is that now I have to install the app before trying it on the phone because if I want to run it on the phone I get an error message saying

bash: cannot set the terminal process group (-1) 
bash: no job control in this shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just installed the Ubuntu SDK PPA and updated to QtCreator 2.8 and now LocalStorage works on the phone and I can run directly on the phone without having to install it every time.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
```

So I think the problem was that...